# Same credit card for multiple Google wallet

Tags: google-wallet

So I live in a country whose federal bank doesn't allow money going outside the country. Our credit cards and debit cards work perfectly fine online/offline inside our country. But nobody can pay to Google / amazon / etc using any of these cards issued from our country.

My cousin lives in the US and he uses Google wallet with his credit cards of US. Can I use the same credit card and pair it up in MY Google wallet?

1. Basically, can me and my cousin both use the same credit card in both of our individual Google Wallets?
2. If not, can he simply send me some money over to my Google Wallet account (which doesn't have any paired up credit cards) and then I could use that balance from my Google Wallet to purchase from Google play?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can.
2. Since you're not in US, your cousin [cannot send funds](http://www.google.co.in/wallet/send-money/) to your Wallet.

> Send money to any friend in the US with an email address